# How to check why files are deleted upon a branch checkout?

Tags: git, version-control

**Background**: I have a git repository hosted on a git portal (namely [gogs](https://gogs.io/)). There are two branches, `master`and `dev`. My understanding of `git` is that once I clone a repository, I can freely switch from one branch to the other and non-committed changes in one branch will discarded when switching to another one. This is however not the case with this repository.

This is the view of the `dev` branch over there:

[image]

As you can see, the `dist` directory lists, among others, the file `401.html`.
The view of the `master` branch is identical, specifically `dist/401.html` is there.

My intent is to move the `dist` directory from both branches to directories on their own somewhere on my system. This is successful with `dev`:

```
+ git clone http://git.example.com/3DS/mysite.git
Cloning into 'mysite'...
remote: Counting objects: 969, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (516/516), done.
remote: Total 969 (delta 485), reused 857 (delta 431)
Receiving objects: 100% (969/969), 17.29 MiB | 2.35 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (485/485), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
+ cd mysite
+ git checkout dev
Branch dev set up to track remote branch dev from origin.
Switched to a new branch 'dev'
+ mv dist /tmp/web/dev
```

I correctly managed to create `/tmp/web/dev` which contains as expected all files from `dist`, among others `401.html`.

I now try to do the same operation for the branch `master`:

```
+ git checkout master
(...)
D       dist/401.html
D       dist/403.html
D       dist/404.html
(...)
Switched to branch 'master'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
+ mv dist /tmp/web/main
```

The content of `/tmp/web/main` is almost none, just a few files remain. `401.html` is gone (with a lot of others, the `D` lines are numerous and I just want to fix the list on `401.html` as an example)

**Why is it so? Why does the move of `dist` in one branch impacts `dist` in another?**

How should the scenario above been done (move `dist` from each branch to its own folder, somewhere)?

*My workaround today is to clone twice but I would like to understand the mistake I am making.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My understanding of `git` is that once I clone a repository, I can freely switch from one branch to the other and non-committed changes in one branch will discarded when switching to another one.

This is just wrong.

If you have made some changes and wish to unmake all of them, you can use `git reset --hard`.  If you run `git checkout`, Git will either succeed and *keep* all the changes, or fail.  If you use `git checkout -f` [as you suggested in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44691622/how-to-check-why-files-are-deleted-upon-a-branch-checkout#comment76372474_44691766), the checkout will succeed by undoing as many of the changes as necessary (which may not be *all* of them).

> How should the scenario above been done (move dist from each branch to its own folder, somewhere)?

If you want to *copy* the contents somewhere outside the repository (so that those contents remain unchanged inside the repository), the easy way to do that is to use a recursive copy, rather than `mv`.  That is, instead of:

> ```
> + cd mysite
> + git checkout dev
> Branch dev set up to track remote branch dev from origin.
> Switched to a new branch 'dev'
> + mv dist /tmp/web/dev
> ```

you might use:

```
+ cd mysite
+ git checkout dev
Branch dev set up to track remote branch dev from origin.
Switched to a new branch 'dev'
+ cp -R dist /tmp/web/dev
```

Now there are no changes in the work-tree.  For myself, I would prefer this method to the `git reset --hard` as `git reset --hard` is a bad habit to learn. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Contrary to what you think, switching branches in Git does not affect the working directory, unless there were some conflict, in which case Git would not even allow you to switch branches.

My guess as to a fix for your situation would be this:

```
git checkout dev
mv dist /tmp/web/dev
git add ...            # add anything moved not already staged
git commit -m 'moved the dist folder'

git checkout master
# at this point, the dist folder should still be in its original location
mv dist /tmp/web/dev
```

Then, do a `git add` and commit on `master` as you did for the `dev` branch.

The bottom line here is that making structural changes to a branch would normally only affect that particular branch.  And you should stage and then commit such changes before trying to switch to another branch.

Comment: Thank you. Isn't `git checkout -f` (https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#git-checkout--f) doing the same thing (in terms of end effect)? I see that the `dist` directory corresponds to the branch (no matter what was done with the other one, including a removal) once I use `-f`.

Comment: I don't know, but I also don't think a force checkout is what you want here.